# How to add multiple rules for Ceiling formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem in Excel where I want to use a formula to calculate the number of delegates a specific county can send to the regional congress.

In this case a county is allowed to send 1 delegate per 300 votes (1-299: 1, 300-599: 2 etc.)
Thus for this case I used the **Ceiling formula** which worked great, but the tricky part is that the rules changes when the amount of votes exceeds 3000, then the rule is 1 delegate per 1000 votes.

How can I add the second rule to the ceiling formula?

data sample[image: 1]

the picture shows some sample data, and for example, D8 I can use the simple Ceiling formula, but for D5 with over 3000 voters, I want a formula that calculates amount of Delegates per 3000 votes + amount per extra 1000 votes.

Comment: May be `IF()` function can help. Post few sample data then desired output and post your current formula.

Comment: What about `=ROUNDUP(A1/300,0)`

Comment: the formula Im using for the Delegate per 300 vote is: =AVRUND.GJELDENDE.MULTIPLUM.OPP.MATEMATISK([@[Total amount votes]]/300) ( the norwegian translate for round up in excel)

Comment: What about this: ```=(A1>3000)*(INT((A1-3000)/1000)+10)+((A1<=3000)*INT(A1/300)+1)*(A1>0)```

Comment: Assumption: number of votes up to 3000: 1 delegate per 300; with 3000 another 1 vote, with 4000 another 1 vote etc. (per 1000 more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this matches your expected outcome:

[image]

Then you may want to try this what I posted in the comments:

```
=(A1>=3000)*(INT(A1/1000)+9)+((A1<3000)*INT(A1/300)+1)*(A1>0)
```

Edit:

I adjusted the formula but for 5004 votes I got a different result to your table ..

Comment: Tried it but I only get syntax error

Comment: The rule is one delegate for each commenced 300 votes up to 3000 votes and then one delegate per commenced 1000 votes.

Comment: Hej! That’s rather surprising as I directly copied the formula from what you see in the screen shot (Excel on Apple PadOS). What happen if you just put the first part in: =(A1>3000)*(INT(A1/1000)+10)

Comment: With 2999 votes there are 10 delegates. With 3000 votes it will be 11 (300 rule) + 3 (1k rule) or rather 10 (300 rule) + 3 (1k rule)? Meaning the 300rule stops at 2999 or at 3000 votes?

Comment: Yes thats correct, 300rule stops av 2999

Comment: Jag pratar inte Norsk ;-)… I updated, but there is a difference for 5004 compared to your table… another rule at 5k?

Comment: No since there is no votes >5000 no new rule for 5 k, but I tried to experiment with the ruleset, and changed the rule to apply on 2100 insted of 3000( other ruleset was the same) but the amount of delgates was not lower which I was expecting

Comment: I see. You can play a bit and modify the formula in different columns to compare the effect. Please feel free to accept/confirm my answer if it solved your question. Tack.